# R - genalg package: Get Fittest From Past Generation

Tags: r, algorithm, genetic

I am doing some optimization with the genalg package in R. Is there any way to get the fittest chromosome from past generations? I am looking for other "close enough" solutions, but it seems to me that all information in the rbga object is from the current (final) generation.

For example, can I get the 100 chromosomes returning the lowest evaluation value in generations 400 - 500?

[image: Example]

Edit: I suppose I could just run the function

```
rbga.bin(size=10, popSize=200, iters= , mutationChance=0.01)
```

for iterations = (400, 401, 402, ..., 498, 499, 500), and pull the best after each additional generation, but that will be extremely slow.

Comment: Do you mean elitism (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm#Elitism)? This can be done with the option `elitism=1` https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/genalg/genalg.pdf (but I suppose you mean something else)

Comment: No, I don't think that's what I'm going for. Elitism just prevents the best chromosome from being changed in the subsequent generation, correct? Unless rbga.bin with elitism = 1 somehow 'marks' the best and preserves it in all future generations (i.e, the best chromosome from generation 0 is guaranteed to be present in generation n, even if there was a better one in gens 1, ... , n-1).

Comment: I now understand that you simply want the best chromosome of each generation *after* the genetic algorithm is finished. I am sorry, I probably can't help you on that. Maybe you will really need to pull the best of each generation manually... If you need to rewrite (at least parts) of genalg yourself, I can only encourage you: A couple of years ago I wrote a genetic algorithm from scratch in Java - it's not that hard.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's what I'll have to do. I'll add my code once I figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generations you have iterated over are not saved by the `rbga.bin()` function, so you can't get the best chromosomes in iteration 400-500 after the algorithms has finished.

However, if you add a monitor function to your `rbga.bin()` call, you can get the information you want. So, include this `monitor` function to your script:

```
monitor <- function(obj) {
  if (obj$iter >= 400) {
    print(paste("GENERATION:", obj$iter))
    print(obj$population[which.min(obj$evaluations), ])
  }
}
```

and add `monitorFunc = monitor` in the `rbga.bin()` like this:

```
rbga.bin(size=10, popSize=200, iters=500, mutationChance=0.01, monitorFunc = monitor)
```

If you like, you can save the output instead of just printing it.